# Why can't I access data after fetching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, jwt

I'm trying to keep session stayed logged in after refreshing the browser. The user data that is being fetched is not rendering after being fetched. The console is saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user'). This is my code for the login/sign up page.

The data I'm trying to access is in the picture below:

[image]

[image]

(Auth.js)

```
const Auth = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        name: "",
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: ""
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }
        })
    }

     const sendRequest = async (type = '') => {
        const res = await axios.post(`/user/${type}`, {
            name: inputs.name,
            email: inputs.email,
            username: inputs.username,
            password: inputs.password,
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
        const data = await res.data;
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(inputs)
        if (isSignup) {
            sendRequest("signup")
                .then((data) => {
                dispatch(authActions.login());
                localStorage.setItem('userId', data.user._id);
                navigate("/posts");
                });
        } else {
            sendRequest("login")
                .then((data) => {
                dispatch(authActions.login());
                localStorage.setItem('userId', data.user._id);
                navigate("/posts");
                });
        }
    }
```

Redux store file

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: { isLoggedIn: false },
    reducers: {
        login(state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = true
        },
        logout(state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = false
        }
    }
})

export const authActions = authSlice.actions

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: authSlice.reducer
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining promises using `.then()` passes the resolved value from one to the next. With this code...

```js
sendRequest("...")
  .then(() => dispatch(authActions.login()))
  .then(() => navigate("/posts"))
  .then(data => localStorage.setItem('token', data.user))
```

You're passing the returned / resolved value from `navigate("/posts")` to the next `.then()` callback. The `navigate()` function returns `void` therefore `data` will be `undefined`.

Also, your redux action doesn't return the user so you can't chain from that either.

To access the `user` data, you need to **return** it from `sendRequest()`...

```js
const sendRequest = async (type = "") => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(`/user/${type}`, { ...inputs });
    console.log("sendRequest", type, data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("sendRequest", type, err.toJSON());
    throw new Error(`sendRequest(${type}) failed`);
  }
};
```

After that, all you really need is this...

```js
sendRequest("...")
  .then((data) => {
    dispatch(authActions.login());
    localStorage.setItem('userId', data.user._id);
    navigate("/posts");
  });
```

---

Since you're using redux, I would highly recommend moving the `localStorage` part out of your component and into your store as a side-effect.

Comment: I changed it to that, but Im still getting the same error in the console.

Comment: @Jason please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72553427/edit) to provide the error details in full, including the stack trace. Point out which line of which file it refers to

Comment: I added the code for the redux store with the action and updated the code to what you suggested. The console is showing 

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
It is from ```sendRequest("login")``` inside of the ```handleSubmit ```

Comment: @Jason so it's **not** _"the same error"_ at all. Could you please update your question with the **actual error message** in full, including the stack trace

Comment: @Jason I've fixed my answer based on your latest update

Comment: I added a picture of the whole error. The error still shows with your updated code. Your updated code also doesnt redirect me to /posts after logging in.

Comment: @Jason make sure you're chaining the `.then()` directly off `sendRequest()`. I've updated my answer to make it clear

Comment: yes it is chained directly. Console is still showing the error for reading 'user' and it does not redirect after login

Comment: @Jason found it. You weren't returning anything from `sendRequest()`. I've updated my answer

Comment: I did had a different code inside ```sendRequest```. I did some changes and with the help you provided, I was able to get my error fixed. Thanks!